# Torque pbs_python submit job error (15025 queue already exists)

Tags: queue, jobs, pbs, qsub, torque

I try to execute this example script (https://oss.trac.surfsara.nl/pbs_python/wiki/TorqueUsage/Scripts/Submit)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/build_pbs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pbs/')
import pbs

server_name = pbs.pbs_default()
c = pbs.pbs_connect(server_name)
attropl = pbs.new_attropl(4)
# Set the name of the job
#
attropl[0].name  = pbs.ATTR_N
attropl[0].value = "test"
# Job is Rerunable
#
attropl[1].name  = pbs.ATTR_r
attropl[1].value = 'y'
# Walltime
#
attropl[2].name  = pbs.ATTR_l
attropl[2].resource = 'walltime'
attropl[2].value = '400'
# Nodes
#
attropl[3].name  = pbs.ATTR_l
attropl[3].resource = 'nodes'
attropl[3].value = '1:ppn=4'
# A1.tsk is the job script filename
#
job_id = pbs.pbs_submit(c, attropl, "A1.tsk", 'batch', 'NULL')
e, e_txt = pbs.error()
if e:
    print e,e_txt
print job_id
```

But shell shows error "15025 Queue already exists". With qsub job submits normally. I have one queue 'batch' on my server. Torque version - 4.2.7. Pbs_python version - 4.4.0.

What  I should to do to start new job?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that error message because there is only one place in the code where PBSE_QUEEXIST is found - its when you're trying to create a queue with the same name as an existing queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here.  First there is an error in pbs_python that maps the 15025 error code to "Queue already exists". Looking at the [source of torque](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/blob/4.2.7/src/include/pbs_error_db.h) we see that 15025 actually maps to the error "Bad UID for job execution", this means that on the torque server, the daemon cannot determine if the user you are submitting as is allowed to run jobs. This could be because of several things:

1. The user you are submitting as doesn't **exist** on the machine running pbs_server
2. The **host** you are submitting from is not in the "submit_hosts" parameter of the pbs_server.

**Solution For 1**

The remedy for this depends on how you authenticate users across systems, you could use [/etc/hosts.equiv](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?hosts.equiv+4) to specify users/hosts allowed to submit, this file would need to be distributed to all the torque nodes as well as the torque server machine.  Using hosts.equiv is pretty insecure, I haven't actually used it in this.  We use a central LDAP server to authenticate all users on the network and do not have this problem. You could also manually add the user to all the torque nodes and the torque server, taking care to make sure the UID is the same on all systems.

**Solution For 2**

If #1 is not your problem (which I doubt it is), you probably need to add the hostname of the machine you're submitting from to the "submit_hosts" parameter on the torque server. This can be accomplished with qmgr:

```
[root@torque_server ]# qmgr -c "set server submit_hosts += hostname.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The pbs python library that you are using was written for torque 2.4.x.

The internal api's for torque were largely rewritten in torque 4.0.x. The library will most likely need to be written for thew new API.

Currently the developers of torque do not test any external libraries. It is possible that they could break at any time.

Comment: This is inaccurate - pbs_python 4.4.0 supports TORQUE 4.2 and higher.